# Шанс выпадение предметов(drop chance) в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Сразу говорю, что ответ, скорее всего, лежит у меня перед глазами, но я его, как обычно, не вижу.(А ещё, скорее всего, я запутался xD)**

 Есть код, в котором есть два массива: *Gameobject items*(сами предметы) и *float dropRate*(С каким шансом выпадет предмет). Так вот, мы постоянно генерируем число(float dropchance) от 0 до 1. Если враг умирает, тогда мы хотим, чтобы шанс из dropRate[] определял: какой предмет выпадет. Но я не как не могу сделать так, чтобы выпадал именно определенный предмет из items[]. Выпадают сразу все вещи из items[]. Да-да, понимаю, что это связано с циклом foreach, но как бы его изменить, чтобы выпадала та вещь, которая мне нужна?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Drop : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] items;
    public int a;
    public float[] dropRate;
    public float dropchance;
    public bool killed = false;
    public float expdropped;

    private GameObject Player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        a = items.Length;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dropchance = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
        Debug.Log(dropchance);
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(killed);
        if (killed)
        {
            killed = false;
            Player.GetComponent<Expirience>().exp += expdropped;
            Vector3 SpawnPoint = transform.position;
            if (items != null) {
                //if (dropchance <= dropRate)
                {
                    for(a=0; a < dropRate.Length;a++) {
                        Debug.Log(dropRate[a]);
                        if (dropRate[a] >= dropchance) {
                            foreach (GameObject item in items)
                            {
                                if (item != null)
                                {
                                    Instantiate(item, SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Вот примерно что я хотел реализовать.]

Comment: Ты Minecraft делаешь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте принудительный выход из цикла путем вызова `break;`

```
var itemDropped = false;
for(a=0; a < dropRate.Length;a++)
{
    Debug.Log(dropRate[a]);
    if (dropRate[a] >= dropchance) {
        foreach (GameObject item in items)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                Instantiate(item, SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                itemDropped = true;
            }
            if(itemDropped) break;
        }
    }
    if(itemDropped) break;
}
```

**UPD:** еще раз внимательно прочитал ваш код- `foreach (GameObject item in items)`.
Данный цикл у вас заставляет выпадать все предметы из списка. Чтобы выбрать только определенные предметы следует сделать такой цикл:

```
foreach (GameObject item in items)
{
    if (item != null && item.dropChance == dropRate[a] )
    {
        Instantiate(item, SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

**UPD2:** В таком случае вам вообще не нужен `foreach`:

```
if (dropRate[a] - dropchance <= 0.05 && -0.05 <= dropRate[a] - dropchance) {
    if (items[a] != null)
    {
        Instantiate(item, SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Или я тупой, или я тупой.
https://imgur.com/a/xDfMunG

Comment: Попробуйте `items.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.dropChance == dropRate[a])`

Comment: А нет, добавил новую библиотеку, теперь пишет, что "x.dropchance" - не содержит...

Comment: А я уже перенес условие во внутренний if... Хорошо тогда.
А как у GameObject определяется шанс дропа? Просто по id?

Comment: Как бы, не как. Это весь код, что я скинул. И там нету нигде нету определение шанса дропа у GameObject. Он определяет шанс дропа в массиве "dropRate". Я хотел как-то связать два массива, чтобы dropRate[1] = items[1]...

Comment: Я обновил ответ в UPD2

Comment: UPD2.
Выпал снова мечь, клон персонажа не падает.
https://imgur.com/a/xDfMunG
И если можете, сделайте чат, а то репутации не хватает.)
P.S обновил imgur, там больше информации стало.

Comment: Всё, я просто изменил знак вот здесь и всё заработало, я протупил немного. Спасибо за помощь. :) https://imgur.com/a/IAw5o3H

Comment: У вас проблема кроется в этом условии `if (dropRate[a] <= dropchance)`
в данном случае 0.1 меньше чем 0.62, соответственно выпадает меч. 
Скорее всего здесь надо сделать разницу с определенной точностью, примерно так `if (dropRate[a] - dropchance <= 0.05 && -0.05 <= dropRate[a] - dropchance)`

Comment: Всё оказалось несколько проще. xD

Comment: Добавил в ответ на всякий случай, ибо такое условие расчета будет более корректно- мы высчитываем разницу между нашим шансом и выпавшим, если оно в пределах устраивающей нас точности- то предмет выпадает. Делать более жесткое сравнение я не стал, ибо так вы очень долго будете ждать выпадения предмета.

Comment: Да, ваш вариант более корректен, поэтому я его и оставлю.